# '"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: zend-framework, environment-variables, wamp

I am trying to create a new zend project using wamp.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\> cd wamp\www\zendtest*

C:\wamp\www\zendtest>C:\wamp\www\zend\bin\zf.bat create project quickstart*


'"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


C:\wamp\www\zendtest>
```

I the environment variable path is

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\Program Files\Zend\MySQL51\bin;C:\wamp\www\zend\bin;

Which is the part I think is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Replace this line in the `zf.bat` file

```
SET PHP_BIN=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\php.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I too have come across the same Error when i started Zend. Here are some ways how to **troubleshoot** this.

1. Make Sure the **PHP Interpreter Path** (For Example, C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\bin) is set to the Environment Variables Path. Only one PHP Interpreter can be set.
2. Make Sure your WAMP Folder & the work directory (For Example, www directory) have **valid permission set** for proper Execution.
3. Make Sure your **Antivirus/Firewall** or any other Software is blocking the Access to php.exe. This i said because, in Windows 7 the User Access Control Feature will not allow execution of php.exe from command line.

And i suggest you work with NetBeans 7.2 which has built-in Support for Zend as well as Doctrine ORM. This is much easier. But you will have to execute the above techniques in that too in the Initial State. The Commands can be directly executed from NetBeans Context Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this error on a new installation even if I added the Environement Path to Windows.

If NetBeans is running, you need to start it as these variables are loaded on startup.